# Display 2D lidar point Javascript

Tags: javascript, 2d, lidar

I want to display lidar 2D points on a webpage.

I've already tried using a canvas, but it's not the best solution because you have to use integer values and my lidar values are small so I have to use floats.

Do you know which library I could use to do this?
Knowing that I need to use CSS transform with translate and scale (display of points over an image).

Thank you!

Here is a canvas rendering with rounding:
[image]

For example, with rviz, I have this display for the same data:
[image]